# schema does not exist and not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a Procedure in snowflake.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
returns string not null language javascript as
$$ 
    var cmd = "select count(1) from Test1.table1";
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    return '1'; 
$$;
```

"table1" existing in schema "schema1" but i am trying to create this procedure in schema2. schema2 does have an access to "table1.

when I run the same query in snowflake web UI with schema "schema2" where i am creating the procedure  `select count(1) from Test1.table1` it is working but inside procedure it is not working and displaying me error

> schema does not exist and not authorized

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test() 
  returns string not null language javascript as 
 $$ 
 var cmd = "select count(1) from Test1.table1";
 var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
 var result = sql.execute();
 return '1';
 $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you fully qualify you names, things just work:

```
use schema test.test;

create schema test.test1;
create table test.test1.table1(id int);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.test1.test()
returns string not null language javascript as
$$ 
    var cmd = "select count(1) from test.test1.table1";
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    return '1'; 
$$;

call test.test1.test();
```

| TEST |
| --- |
| 1 |

```
create schema test.test2;

use schema test.test2;

call test.test1.test();
```

| TEST |
| --- |
| 1 |

```
use schema test.test2;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.test2.test()
returns string not null language javascript as
$$ 
    var cmd = "select count(1) from test.test1.table1";
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    return 'called table1 from schema2'; 
$$;

call test.test2.test();
```

| TEST |
| --- |
| called table1 from schema2 |

### So why your error?

The below SQL I have made non fully qualified. So the function will be in the current scehma. Which for me is `test.test2`. But now I am referring to schema `schema1.table1` and `schema1` does not exist. thus the error message when I run the code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
returns string not null language javascript as
$$ 
    var cmd = "select count(1) from schema1.table1";
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    return 'called table1 from schema2'; 
$$;

call test.test2.test();
```

gives:

> SQL compilation error:
>
> Schema 'TEST.SCHEMA1' does not exist or not authorized.
>
> At Statement.execute, line 4 position 21

The other possible outcome is you have the function defined as `EXECUTE AS OWNER` and the two functions do have two different owners, with different owning permissions. But I am going to doubt that.